# persistent bottom nav bar not working properly

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to apply persistent_bottom_nav_bar but I keep getting error. I got similar answers and tried to follow https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar

These are the errors that I keep getting.

`The method '_BottomBarState' isn't defined for the type 'BottomBar'.` & `1 positional argument(s) expected, but 0 found.`

```
class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<BottomBar> createState() => _BottomBarState();
}
PersistentTabController _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);

//Screens for each nav items.
List<Widget> _NavScreens() {
  return [
    HomeScreen(),
    const Text("History"),
  ];
}
List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
  return [
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
      icon: Icon(FluentSystemIcons.ic_fluent_home_regular),
      title: "Home",
      activeColorPrimary: Colors.blueGrey,
    ),
    PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
      title: ("History"),
      activeColorPrimary: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
    ),
  ];
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: PersistentTabView(
      controller: _controller,
      screens: _NavScreens(),
      items: _navBarsItems(),
      confineInSafeArea: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
      decoration: NavBarDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
      navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style9,
    ),
  );
}
```

This is the original bottom bar that I want to keep fixed in all screens

```
class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    HomeScreen(),
    const Text("History"),
  ];
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      //print('Tapped index is: ${_selectedIndex}');
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions[_selectedIndex],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
...............................
            items: const [
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(FluentSystemIcons.ic_fluent_home_regular),
                  label: "Home"),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(FluentSystemIcons.ic_fluent_history_regular),
                  label: "History"),
            ],),],),);}}
```

How to apply presistent bottom bar to my project without changing the design? Why am I reciving this error and how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**persistent_bottom_nav_bar.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'bottom_nav_bar.dart';

class MyPersistentBottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyPersistentBottomNavBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Persistent Bottom Nav Bar',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple),
      home: const BottomNavBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

**bottom_nav_bar.dart :**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2/persistent-tab-view.dart';

import 'pages/home_page.dart';
import 'pages/explore_page.dart';
import 'pages/add_page.dart';
import 'pages/inbox_page.dart';
import 'pages/shopping_page.dart';

class BottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomNavBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PersistentTabController controller;
    controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);

    List<Widget> _buildScreens() {
      return [
        const HomePage(),
        const ExplorePage(),
        const AddPage(),
        const InboxPage(),
        const ShoppingPage(),
      ];
    }

    List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
      return [
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
          title: ("Home"),
          activeColorPrimary: Colors.deepPurple,
          inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        ),
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.explore),
          title: ("Explore"),
          activeColorPrimary: Colors.deepPurple,
          inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        ),
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
          activeColorPrimary: Colors.deepPurple,
          inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        ),
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.email),
          title: ("Inbox"),
          activeColorPrimary: Colors.deepPurple,
          inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        ),
        PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
          title: ("Shop"),
          activeColorPrimary: Colors.deepPurple,
          inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ];
    }

    return PersistentTabView(
      context,
      controller: controller,
      screens: _buildScreens(),
      items: _navBarsItems(),
      confineInSafeArea: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white, // Default is Colors.white.
      handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true, // Default is true.
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset:
          true, // This needs to be true if you want to move up the screen when keyboard appears. Default is true.
      stateManagement: true, // Default is true.
      hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows:
          true, // Recommended to set 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' as true while using this argument. Default is true.
      decoration: NavBarDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
      ),
      popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
      popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
      itemAnimationProperties: const ItemAnimationProperties(
        // Navigation Bar's items animation properties.
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        curve: Curves.ease,
      ),
      screenTransitionAnimation: const ScreenTransitionAnimation(
        // Screen transition animation on change of selected tab.
        animateTabTransition: true,
        curve: Curves.ease,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      ),
      navBarStyle:
          NavBarStyle.style15, // Choose the nav bar style with this property.
    );
  }
}
```

***Please see code for other pages from the GitHub URL below:***

```dart
https://github.com/md-siam/package_of_the_day/tree/master/lib/51_persistent_bottom_nav_bar/pages
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this code.It runs fine, can you please try?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:minawill/ui/home/home.dart';

class BottomBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomBar> createState() => _BottomBarState();
}

class _BottomBarState extends State<BottomBar> {

  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    HomeScreen(),
    const Text("History"),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      //print('Tapped index is: ${_selectedIndex}');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _widgetOptions[_selectedIndex],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
            BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
            items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
        label: "Home"),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
    label: "History"),
    ],),],),);}
}
```

i have added a photo of my output.Please check
[image: Output of persistent bottom nav bar]